# Can't connect to Windows machine via https

Tags: python, windows, https

I have a python server (BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer) running on an XP machine (SP3) as a Windows Service. I am trying to connect via https, but get a timeout.

the command `netstat -an | find "5400"` gives

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:5400        0.0.0.0:0        LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:5400        0.0.0.0:0        LISTENING
```

I am fairly new to server programming, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

EDIT:

I used netcat (`netcat -l -v -p 5400`) to set up a simple server and tried to connect to that. I had no luck there either, so I am updating with some more information.

When I connect to the netcat server using `telnet localhost 5400` I get the message: 
`DNS fwd/rev mismatch: localhost != HUNGRY`

(HUNGRY being the name of the compy).

The machine I am trying to connect to is on a wireless router with the IP address 198.183.3.187 (obtained from `ipconfig`) and listening on port 5400.

I asked this question on ServerFault first, but had the question closed (for reasons I still do not understand).

Comment: do you have this port open on your windows xp machine, or might there be a firewall blocking the requests?

Comment: According to netstat, the port is listening. Connecting to localhost from the same machine works fine, but trying to connect from outside gets a timeout. I was told by IT that this machine has no firewall, but I will do some digging to find out for sure.

Comment: The machine may not have a firewall what about the routers access control lists?

Comment: Turns out the wireless network for our office rejects any outside requests. I was trying to connect from a cellular data network. I am able to connect now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the wireless network for our office rejects any outside requests. I was trying to connect from a cellular data network. Once I connected to our wireless signal I was able to connect.